# Does using static variables in django views a good practise?

Tags: python, django, django-views, static-variables

Assuming the get method is called  at least one time before the post method.(This is not my actual code, if there's any silly mistake, don't consider it, my question is CAN I INSTANTIATE AND USE STATIC VARIABLE LIKE BELOW)

```
class McqView(View):
      course=None
      all_questions=None
      start_time=None
      def get(self,request,someid):
             if not McqView.course:
                 McqView.course = Course.objects.get(id=someid)
             if not McqView.all_questions:
                 McqView.all_questions = Question.objects.filter(course=McqExamView.course)
             if not McqView.start_time:
                 McqView.start_time = datetime.now()
             #using the static variables somewhere here

      def post(self,request):
              #using the same static variables somewhere here
```

I thought of using the two as member variables but it is not possible. So I thought of using the two as static variables. will any problem arise while using this method? like
1.The static variables become None
2.The static variables gets instantiated more than once.
If the second case happens, the start_time variable value will become wrong.

Please tell me whether this is a wrong approach, if it is wrong tell me an alternative way of doing the same.

Answer (score -1):

While a minimal class-based view does not require any class attributes to perform its job, class attributes are useful in many class-based designs, and there are two ways to configure or set class attributes.

The first is the standard Python way of sub-classing and overriding attributes and methods in the subclass. So that if your parent class had an attribute `greeting` like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

    class GreetingView(View):
        greeting = "Good Day"
    
        def get(self, request):
            return HttpResponse(self.greeting)
```

You can override that in a subclass:

```
class MorningGreetingView(GreetingView):
    greeting = "Morning to ya"
```

Another option is to configure class attributes as keyword arguments to the `as_view()` call in the URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', GreetingView.as_view(greeting="G'day")),
]
```

**Note** - While your class is instantiated for each request dispatched to it, class attributes set through the `as_view()` entry point are configured only once at the time your URLs are imported.

Comment: mentioned 2 methods to avoid class attributes as mentioned in Django Docs